# Convergence of expecations implies convergence of positive and negative parts?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, self-learning, expectation

If we have $E|X_n| \rightarrow E|X|$ does that imply
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E X_n^\pm = X^\pm
\end{equation}
How about if we only have $EX_n \rightarrow EX$? Is this true in general for real numbers?

**Edit:** I think the answer is probably no, but how about if we have an additional condition, say $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} EX_n^+ = EX^+$ and $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}EX_n^- = EX^-$, does that imply the limsups are also equal and so we have the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $\mathbb{E}|X_n| \to \mathbb{E}|X|$: No, this does not imply the statement. Simply consider $X_n := 1$ for $n$ odd and $X_n := -1$ for $n$ even.
2. $\mathbb{E}X_n \to \mathbb{E}X$: Again, no. Consider $$X_n \sim \frac{1}{2} \delta_n + \frac{1}{2} \delta_{-n}.$$
3. With the additional condition: Consider the sequence $(X_1,\ldots,X_k,0,X_{k+1},\ldots,X_{2k},0,\ldots)$ for some $k \geq 1$ where $(X_n)_n$ is as in 2.

**Remark.** A sufficient condition is e.g. that $X_n \to X$ in $L^1$.

Comment: Thanks, you're good at this, can you please do me a huge favor and answer why, if this is the case, that an author made such a conclusion here [sandwiching-limsups-liminfs-of-expectations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896770/sandwiching-limsups-liminfs-of-expectations)

Comment: @Stacy I don't know, I don't think it's obvious. I would use a totally different argumentation (which works out if $X_n,X \in L^1$). By the way, if you like this answer, you can upvote it by clicking on the up arrow next to it.

Comment: I already tried upvoting your answer, it won't let me because I'm not advanced enough as a member :(

Comment: So it seems even with almost sure convergence it's not enough to conclude this

Comment: @Stacy Ah, okay, I see. And no, your conclusion is not correct - if $\mathbb{E}|X_n| \to \mathbb{E}|X|$, $X \in L^1$ and $X_n \to X$ almost surely, then the statement holds true. I simply don't see why the given proof is correct.